# How can I bring a process window to the front using AutoIt3?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autoit-c#-wrapper

```
if (au3.WinExists(processName, "") == 0)
            {
                au3.Run(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Paint.exe", "", au3.SW_SHOW);
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                au3.MouseClick("LEFT", 358, 913, 1, -1);

            }
            else
            {
                au3.Run(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Paint.exe", "", au3.SW_SHOW);
Thread.Sleep(10000);
                au3.MouseClick("LEFT", 358, 913, 1, -1);
            }
```

I'm using `AutoIt3XClass` which is part of the `AutoIt3XLib`
So I'm checking if the process exist or not. If not run it and it will show in the front in the center of the screen.

The problem is if the process already running and I want to maximize it and bring it to the front to the center of the screen.

I didn't find any properties in `au3(AutoIt3XClass)` that will bring it to the front. Doing `au3.Run` bring it to the front but i don't want to run it again if it's already running.

So, maybe `au3` have a property to just show/bring it to the front ? If not maybe using other way to bring it to the front ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

If process is running, bring it to front maximized and perform mouse click. If process is not running, run process and cache it's id, get process by that id, bring it to front and wait for 10 seconds before performing mouse click. I tried this out and is working as expected.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr handle);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr handle, int nCmdShow);

private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

public static void BringToFront(IntPtr handle)
{
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;

    // Maximize window
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);

    SetForegroundWindow(handle);
}
```

Program logic:

```
AutoItX3 au3 = new AutoItX3();

string processName = "mspaint";
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

if (processes.Length == 0) // Process not running
{
    int processId = au3.Run(@"C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe", "", au3.SW_SHOW);
    Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
    IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
    BringToFront(handle);
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    au3.MouseClick("LEFT", 358, 913, 1, -1);
}
else // Process running
{
    BringToFront(processes[0].MainWindowHandle);
    au3.MouseClick("LEFT", 358, 913, 1, -1);
}
```

Comment: In the if else in the first part I need to make au3.Run but on the else part I need too ? Or just BringToFront ? In my code I did Run twice in the if and in the else.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not sure why are you checking if (au3.WinExists(processName, "") == 0) when you're going to do the same thing wether it's true or false.

Comment: Then what should I check for ? Only if the process is running or not ? I want to check if the process is already running just bring it to front and make the au3 mouseclick. But if the process is not running yet then first run it then sleep 10 seconds then make the click.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ProcessExists instead of WinExsits. To bring the window to the front, you can use WinActivate.